# SwiftUI: How to clip an image overlay to its view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following view displaying a book image:

```
struct MaskContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .purple, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .padding(10)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .padding(20)
                .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                    Image("book")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .colorMultiply(.black)
                        .opacity(0.1)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-20), anchor: .center)
                        .offset(x: 50.0, y: 10)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .clipped()
                    
                }
            Text("Tourism")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to clip the image to the rectangle to which it's added as an overlay but it's overflowing onto the background rectangles. How can I achieve this?

The image:

[image]

Current Result:

[image]

Clipping the rectangle containing the overlay doesn't fix it either:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clip the `Rectangle` instead, to remove the part of the image that's "sticking out" of the rectangle's frame.

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    .padding(20)
    .overlay(alignment: .center) {
        Image("book")
            ...
        
    }
    .clipped()// here!
```

If you want to clip the image with the green-yellow area only, you should add the `padding` of the rectangle *last*, after clipping.

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    .overlay {
        Image("book")
            ...
    }
    .clipped()
    .padding(20) // move the padding here
```

Alternatively, don't use an `overlay` and just add the image to the `ZStack`, and use an insetted rectangle as the clip shape.

```
// directly in the ZStack
Image("book")
    ...
    .clipShape(Rectangle().inset(by: 20)) // 20, because that is the padding for the green-yellow rectangle
```

Comment: It did not work. I added the clipped() modifier to the Rectangle like you suggested.  Note that I removed the clipShape() modifier as that didnt seem to have any effect. I've updated the question with the result.

Comment: @batman I don't see anything wrong with the image? Do you want it to clip the red/orange border too?

Comment: It should be clipped within the rectangle having yellow and green gradient background. That's the one which has the image as an overlay. The rectangles beneath it should not have the image overlay spilling onto them.

Comment: @batman Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MaskContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .purple, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .padding(10)
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .green], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .padding(20)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                Image("Book")
                    .resizable()
                    //You can brainstorm here....
                    .frame(width: 160, height: 200)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .colorMultiply(.black)
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-20), anchor: .center)
                    .offset(x: 20.0, y: 10)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    .clipped()
                
            }
        Text("Tourism")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
}
```

}
[You can see the result in the attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2LKs.png)